# WCF - Who is connecting to me

Tags: .net, wcf

With WCF, how can I determine who is connecting to my server?

Background: I have a set of WCF clients and servers. I suspect one client is pointed to the wrong server, so I want to log all the connections to that server. I don't know which client it is, so I have to check it on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest in 3.5 via [RemoteEndpointMessageProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.remoteendpointmessageproperty.aspx); see [here](http://nayyeri.net/blog/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5/).

Comment: Is there a cleaner syntax than "Dim remoteAddress = CType(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties("System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty"), System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty).Address"

Comment: Well you could at least avoid the string literal (see the "here" link in the answer posted by Marc).

Answer (score 1):

```
OperationContext opCtx = OperationContext.Current;
EndpointAddress from = opCtx.IncomingMessageHeaders.From;
```